# my mesh got spikes and idk how to fix it

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

soo.. im working with blender for the first time with a tutorial, and after i did some sculpturing, my whole mesh started to do this.. i thought it was a visual error from reloading the view or so but after reopening the software i had the same problem.. does someone know a fix to this?

Comment: so how does it look like in Edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Blender as well, but my first thought is that you need to recalculate your faces. Have you tried that?